# Does $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{23}+\dots$ converge?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Let $d(m)$ be the number of positive divisors of $m$ [including $1$ and $m$]. Let $p_k$ be the $k^\text{th}$ prime number. Consider the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{d(p_{k}-1)}}{p_{k}}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{23}+\dots$$

> Does the series converge? If yes, then what is its value of
>   convergence?

Any help/hint will be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: The term $-1/19$ is wrong. $d(18)$ is even.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Since $d(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square, your sum is equal to the sum of reciprocals of primes, minus twice the sum of reciprocals of primes of the form $n^2+1$. But we have
$$\sum_{p=n^2+1\text{ for some $n$}}\frac{1}{p}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+1}<\infty,$$
so your sum diverges to infinity.

Comment: TBH I don't understand this answer. I can follow your argumentation until the last line. Why does the given chain of inequalities implies the divergence of the original series? I mean, IIRC the sum of all reciprocals of primes diverges and so we are subtracting a finite number of an infinite which is still infinite. But, are we allowed to do so? How can on justify the rewritten form of the series (as it's afterall apparently a divergent series)?

Comment: @mrtaurho You can write a partial sum for the original series as a sum of reciprocals of primes up to some bound minus twice the sum of reciprocals of primes of the special form. You get something tending to infinity minus something bounded, so the thing tends to infinity.

Comment: Ah, got it now. Thank you!